# PyCharm synchronization between local files and (local) docker

Tags: python, docker, pycharm

I know that as of now (june 21) PyCharm does not support a fully remote development the way VSCode does; however, it supports a remote interpreter and in the case of ssh connection, it supports an automatic upload of local files to the server.

My question is: can I use an interpreter running in docker container and synchronize my files with the files within the container?

Apparently, I can define a remote docker interpreter and set up a "Mapping":
[image]

However, I don't see any way how to automatically upload my local files / changes to the container. When I try to configure a new deployment, I don't see any docker option:
[image]

Am I missing something, or is it like PyCharm does not support such "Docker deployment"?

([This](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360009107720-Mapping-local-dir-when-using-docker-interpreter) might be related, but not a clear conclusion there...)

(UPDATE: after studying more, I'm not even sure if I can use interpreter in a docker container. It seems that pycharm only enables a docker image, and anything I would do inside docker... is gone in the next session. Or am I wrong?)